# How can I replace part of a panel via a selection change in a Bokeh figure?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviz, pyviz, panel-pyviz

Normally, I am able to replace parts of a panel via `pop` and `insert`, which updates any existing panels automatically. However, if these are triggered from a bokeh `selected.on_change` callback,
existing panels do not update.

For example, running the following in JupyterLab works

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import panel as pn


pn.extension()

def create_figure():
    src = ColumnDataSource(flowers)
    p = figure(height=200, width=200, tools='box_select')
    p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=src)
    return p

pnl = pn.panel(pn.Row(create_figure, create_figure))
pnl
```

The displayed panel will update as expected when I run the following in the next cell:

```py
pnl.pop(0)
pnl.insert(0, figure)
```

However, if I do the same thing via a callback when the selection of the column data source changes, the panel does not update as I select data points in the plot:

```py
def replace_plot(attr, old, new):
    pnl.objects.pop(0)
    pnl.objects.insert(0, figure)

def create_figure():
    src = ColumnDataSource(flowers)
    p = figure(height=200, width=200, tools='box_select')
    p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=src)
    src.selected.on_change('indices', replace_plot)
    return p

pnl = pn.panel(pn.Row(create_figure, create_figure))
pnl
```

What does work is to replace the entire `pnl.objects` with a new list:

```py
def replace_plot(attr, old, new):
    pnl.objects = [figure]
```

Strangely, this only work when I call `pnl.show()` to display the panel in a new browser tab, in the notebook I need to display the panel again in a new cell to see the update. I tried replacing individual items in the `objects` list via indexing, but this worked the same as `pop` and `insert`, the panel did not update automatically.

Is there a way to replace parts of a panel vi a `selected.on_change` callback and have it refresh automatically (preferably inside the notebook but via `show` also works)?

Versions:

```
-----
bokeh       2.0.1
pandas      1.0.3
panel       0.9.5
-----
IPython             6.5.0
jupyter_client      5.2.3
jupyter_core        4.6.3
jupyterlab          2.1.0
notebook            5.6.0
-----
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 23 2020, 23:03:20) [GCC 7.3.0]
Linux-5.6.13-arch1-1-x86_64-with-arch
4 logical CPU cores
-----
Session information updated at 2020-05-21 18:38
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you get no answer to this question on SO, you can also try posting your question on https://discourse.holoviz.org/

Comment: Thanks @SandervandenOord, I opened one at https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/how-can-i-replace-part-of-a-panel-via-a-selection-change-in-a-bokeh-figure/701 previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in panel, now being tracked at https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/1368. For the time being, the following snippet works around the problem:

```py
from panel.io.notebook import push

def replace_plot(attr, old, new):
    for ref in pnl._models:
        _, _, doc, comm = pn.state._views[ref]
        doc.hold()
        pnl[0] = 1
        push(doc, comm)
    for ref in pnl._models:
        _, _, doc, comm = pn.state._views[ref]
        doc.unhold()
```